# Can anyone please explain me DNS and DHCP in easy languguage

Tags: dhcp, dns

Hey I just started to learn `Networking` and I have some problems understanding the `DNS` and `DHCP`. I tried many books but they defined it a total technical language and I can't understand them. So can anyone please explain me those terms in **easy languages** and in **easy terms**

Comment: Besides this question being too broad, one could argue this is expected to be common knowledge on this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DNS** is used for access to websites using an easy address like `http://google.com` instead of technical address `http://74.125.224.72`.

[image]

When you enter to `http://google.com` your computer first check its own **DNS cache** to looking for the ip (If you have entered before it would be here).  If the ip cannot be found, the request is sent to the **local DNS server**. If it still cannot be found then the request is sent to the **Domain Root Server**. Finally the ip is sent to the host and saved in the cache for future requests.

A graphic example:
[image]

**DHCP** is a protocol used by the router to assign automatic the private ip address to each device in a network. There is 3 ways to assign ip addresses automatic to the hosts:

- **Manual Assignment**: The admin manually configure the ip addresses for the client in the DHCP server. When one host ask for one IP address, the server check the MAC address from the host y assigns the ip configured by the admin.
- **Automatic Assignment**: The first time that one host is connected, the DHCP server assign an ip randomly.
- **Dynamic Assignment**: The DHCP server assign an ip address temporarily. When the time is over the request has to be renovated.

Is not a technical definition but I think it can help you to have a global idea.

Comment: By `Domain Root Server` do you mean the DNS servers marked as `com DNS Server` and `org DNS Server` or the one marked as `Root DNS Server` in the diagram provided by you

Comment: I mean the one marked as `Root DNS Server`. When the Root DNS Server receives a request, it answers with the `TLD: Top Level Domain` which can be  `.com` or `.edu` for example. Then it looks for the IP address in the DNS tables from the TLD. For example:

-Request  Ip Address of Google.com to the Root DNS Server.
-It answers that it is in the .com TLD and not in .net or .edu TLD.
-Then looks for the IP address in the .com TLD.

Comment: Protocols above OSI layer-4 are explicitly off-topic here. This question (if the focus were more narrow) and answer are more appropriate for [sf] or [su].